# Assign different links to specific items in an array

Tags: javascript

Thanks to awesome developers who helped me in this forum, I've made a small project where a script is generating some content with links inside a div.

Currently, the code assigns the same array of links for all the countries but now I want to differentiate a little. I would like some countries to have the option to use the the array with 2 links, another country the array with 3 links and another country the array with 4 links. The rest can use 1 link.

How can I achieve that based on the existing code?

```js
let countrySelect = document.getElementsByClassName('countries');

// link for other countries
let link1 = ["https://www.example1.com"];

// links for China
let links2 = ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com"];

// links for USA
let links3 = ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example2.com"];

// links for Australia
let links4 = ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example3.com", "https://www.example4.com"];

// make an array of countries
let countries = ["China", "USA", "Canada", "UK", "Japan", "Australia", "Austria", "Czech Republic"];

countries.forEach(country => {
    let makeDiv = document.createElement("div");
    makeDiv.id = country;
    let h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    h4.innerText = country;
    makeDiv.appendChild(h4);

    links2.forEach((link, i) => {
        let tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = link;
        tag.innerText = `Link${i+1}`;
        makeDiv.appendChild(tag);
    });

    countrySelect[0].appendChild(makeDiv);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.countries h4 {
  
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.countries a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="countries"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object that maps country names to the list of links.

```js
let countrySelect = document.getElementsByClassName('countries');

let countryLinks = {
  other: ["https://www.example1.com"],
  China: ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com"],
  USA: ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example2.com"],
  Australia: ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example3.com", "https://www.example4.com"]
};

// make an array of countries
let countries = ["China", "USA", "Canada", "UK", "Japan", "Australia", "Austria", "Czech Republic"];

countries.forEach(country => {
    let makeDiv = document.createElement("div");
    makeDiv.id = country;
    let h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    h4.innerText = country;
    makeDiv.appendChild(h4);
    let links2 = countryLinks[country] || countryLinks.other;
    links2.forEach((link, i) => {
        let tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = link;
        tag.innerText = `Link${i+1}`;
        makeDiv.appendChild(tag);
    });

    countrySelect[0].appendChild(makeDiv);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.countries h4 {
  
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.countries a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="countries"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the tool you're using.

Comment: I thought the problem you're having there is with tooltips.

Comment: PS Don't put a link in backticks in comments, it's not clickable.